# C++ can't delete char*, keeps corrupting heap

Tags: c++, delete-operator

Language: C++, Compiler: MSVS (/Za) and g++ (yes, it must work on both), Level: beginner

I'm attempting to delete the data from a char* so that I can reallocate it and continue my program.  I create a new char*, assign the value of the command line parameter to it, do some validation, then if the validation fails it should deallocate the char* and let me assign new data to the var however I'm getting a "Heap corruption detected" error in visual studio.  I'm curious about both the fix for my current code and any other ways this could be done more clearly/concisely.

In main():

```
//...
//make non constant versions to be messed with
char* ba = new char[ strlen(argv[4]) + 1 ];
char* num = new char[ strlen(argv[2]) + 1 ];

//make non constant versions of commandline stuff
nonConstant( argv[4], argv[2], ba, num );

//do the conversion and printing
convert( ba, num );
//...
```

convert does this:

```
//...
if( error ) {
    getNew(ba, num, &error);
}
//...
```

and here is getNew:

```
void getNew( char* ba, char* num, bool error ) {

//if there's an error in their numbers let them input new stuff and check to see if that's valid
while( error ) {
    //tell the user that the input was bad an prompt for more, use getline because strings are weird
    //cin stuff here (this part works, no problems)

    //free up base and num so I can reassign them
    delete[] ba; //<--this line fails
    delete[] num;

    //set lengths = to lengths of input + 1 for \0
    ba = new char[ inputBa.length() + 1 ];
    num = new char[ inputNum.length() + 1 ];

    //do the assignment of new input back to base and num
    inputBa.copy( ba, inputBa.length(), 0 );
    inputNum.copy( num, inputNum.length(), 0 );

    //ensure that the input was good this time
    validateInput( ba, num, error );
}
```

Comment: Enable hints and warnings when you compile.

Comment: If parameter `error` of `getNew` is declared with type `bool`, why does the corresponding argument in `getNew` call look as `&error`??? I mean it could be formally correct, since pointers are convertible to `bool` type. But still, what was the idea here?

Comment: @KenWhite, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass parameters by char *& will fix the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reassgnReference( char * &ba, char * &num );
void reassgnPointerToPointer( char ** ba, char ** num );

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    if ( argc > 4 )
    {
        char * ba = new char[strlen( argv[ 4 ] ) + 1];
        char * num = new char[strlen( argv[ 2 ] ) + 1];

        strncpy( ba, argv[ 4 ], strlen( argv[ 4 ] ) );
        strncpy( num, argv[ 2 ], strlen( argv[ 2 ] ) );

        printf( "In the beginning, ba = %s, num = %s\n", ba, num );

        reassgnReference( ba, num );
        printf( "reassgnReference(), ba = %s, num = %s\n", ba, num );

        reassgnPointerToPointer( &ba, &num );
        printf( "reassgnPointerToPointer(), ba = %s, num = %s\n", ba, num );
}
else
{
    printf( "%s Expects at least 4 arguments\n", argv[ 0 ] );
}

return( 0 );
}

void reassgnReference( char *& ba, char *& num )
{
    delete[] ba;
    delete[] num;

    char const * const newBa = "ba from reference";
    char const * const newNum = "num from reference";

    ba = new char[strlen( newBa ) + 1];
    num = new char[strlen( newNum ) + 1];

    strncpy( ba, newBa, strlen( newBa ) );
    strncpy( num, newNum, strlen( newNum ) );
}

void reassgnPointerToPointer( char ** ba, char ** num )
{ 
    delete[] *ba;
    delete[] *num;

    char const * const newBa = "ba from pointer to pointer";
    char const * const newNum = "num from pointer to pointer";

    *ba = new char[strlen( newBa ) + 1];
    *num = new char[strlen( newNum ) + 1];

    strncpy( *ba, newBa, strlen( newBa ) );
    strncpy( *num, newNum, strlen( newNum ) );
}
```

Comment: A little more explanation would be appreciated, or link to some documentation/examples if that's easier.

Comment: And it didn't fix anything to change that though I don't really know why that would be better. The research I did said that if I pass by reference I cannot re-assign it, which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I added examples of how to do it with references to pointers and pointers to pointers.  They both work.  You cannot re-assign a reference but you can reassign the value of the reference which is what is happening in reassgnReference().

Comment: Ok, I'm not really sure what ended up fixing this, but having a clear example of both ways to pass in my char* really helped.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

**Stop**! Switch to `std::string`, immediately.

This will both fix your code, and be more clear/concise, as requested.

Comment: Well, if the problem is indeed in OP's lack of understanding of reference and value semantics (when passing arguments), then switching to `std::string` by itself will not fix much. It might stop crashes, but it won't make the code work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

If looks like your `getNew` function can reallocate the memory local `ba` and `num` are pointing to, i.e `delete[]` it and `new[]` it again.

But what about `ba` and `num` in the caller, in `convert`? Also, what about `ba` and `num` in `main`? They are passed to `getNew` by value, which means that they remain unchanged. They continue to point to their original (now dead) memory locations. I would guess that you continue to use those now-meaningless `ba` and `num` values in `convert` and in `main` until they cause the crash. For example, if you call `getNew` with those old pointer values again, `getNew` will likely fail at `delete[]`.

Also, it is not immediately clear what `error` is in `convert`. Why are you passing it as `&error` (likely a pointer) when `getNew` actually expects a `bool` argument? It will compile, but it looks like a problem anyway.

Comment: good catch on the `&error` thing, I use it as a flag in my validate function if there's an error somewhere.  My understanding though was that by sending char* around I was not sending the value and was instead passing the pointer to the value, which would mean that once changed in one location it's changed in all locations.  Is that not the case?  If it's not the case what do I need to do to make it the case?

Comment: @dlkulp: Well, yes, by passing a `char *` pointer you can change the *pointed value* and it will "change everywhere". But if you change the *pointer itself*, it will not "change everywhere". If you want to change the `char *` pointer in the callee and then see that change in the caller, by the same logic you have to essentially pass around a pointer-to-pointer (a `char **`). Or in C++ you can use a *reference*-to-pointer to achieve the same effect. A reference to pointer is declared as `char *&`.

Comment: but a `char *&` can't be changed right?  So I would want `char **` in this situation which would allow me to change where the pointer is pointing to?